# Customizing UIButton's titleLabel with iOS 5's Appearance API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm trying to customize the appearance of the title label in a UIButton with the new appearance API, but haven't found anything that would work. It seems that the following code ought to work:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 2)];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:17]];
```

But I suppose that the UILabel is not actually a subview of the button. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I think the button may be overwriting the appearance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you modify the title label directly by using the `titleLabel` property of `UIButton`?

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:17];
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
```

Untested, but that should work, right?

EDIT:
Why don't you just create a subclass of UIButton and add these two lines?

Comment: That will work for a single UIButton, but what I'm trying to do is style all UIButtons.

Comment: I guess I could create a subclass, but I was hoping to do as much in the framework as possible.

Comment: this capability will be present in iOS6

Comment: Sorry, I meant the (appearance) API, not the framework. Since @CSmith confirmed that what I'm trying to do won't be present until iOS 6, I'll go ahead with your solution.